# Server seems to drop connections in accept

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I'm having trouble with implementing a server that has a master thread invoking `accept()` and then passing on the new client socket to a slave thread (I have a fixed-size thread pool created previously).

It is implemented in a way that I'm using a simple array of integers to represent a stack of client sockets, which gets filled up by successful `accept()` calls. There is one mutex per slave thread, and each slave is implicitly free if its current client file descriptor is set to `-1` (it is set as such in the thread code, at the end of satisfying a request).

In a use-case, I have a shell script launching a given number of clients, for example, six concurrent clients (six processes). Checking TCP connection set up, none of the clients receive any errors on `connect()`.

Now here is the problem. On this specific test scenario with **six clients**, the server is only printing **five `accept()` success messages** (`> Server got connection from ...`) from an **expected six**. I'm not sure but it feels like one of the client connections to accept is simply being lost!

Even stranger, I added a `continue` (`//MAGICAL TEST`) between receiving the accepted socket and dispatching it to a slave thread. With that `continue` in place, no slaves receive work BUT now all of the client connections are printed as expected. I'm not exactly sure, but is it possible that while the master thread dispatches work to slaves, one of the client connections in the accept queue gets dropped?

EDIT: this is only happening when I have a number of slave threads lower than the number of simultaneous requests. Still, I do not understand why one of the extra connects seems to not be printed by the master thread in that case (e.g. 2 slaves versus 6 concurrent requests).

Thread-local data defined in the following:

```
#define PENDING_CONNS 35
typedef struct _ThreadData {
    pthread_t m_Thread;
    pthread_mutex_t m_Mutex;
    char* m_Task;
    int m_ClientFD;
    unsigned int m_Index;
    unsigned short int m_Networking;
    char* m_OutputDir;
} ThreadData;
static ThreadData *g_Workers = NULL;
static unsigned int g_NumWorkers = 0;
static pthread_barrier_t g_StartBarrier;
```

And then here's the master thread section:

```
/*
 * Executed by the coordinating thread. Awaits and passes new client connections to free working threads.
 */
int RunServer(char* port) {
    // Listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd.
    int sockfd, new_fd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;

    // Connector's address information.
    struct timeval timeout;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
    socklen_t sin_size;

    //  struct sigaction sa; //TODO: possible signal handling later.
    int yes = 1;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int rv;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, port, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "> Server: getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return -1;
    }

    // Loop through all the results and bind to the first we can
    for (p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("> Server: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
            perror("> Server: setsockopt");
            return -1;
        }

        if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("> Server: bind");
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "> Server: failed to bind\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // All done with this structure.
    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
    //PENDING_CONNS defined as 25
    if (listen(sockfd, PENDING_CONNS) == -1) {
        perror("> Server: listen");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("> Server: waiting for connections...\n");

    fd_set_blocking(sockfd, 0); // NON BLOCKING
    int requestStack[1000];
    int stackTop = 0;

    // Main loop of coordinating thread.
    while (1) {
        sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
        new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &their_addr, &sin_size);
        if (new_fd == -1) {
            //queue was probably empty...
        }
        else {
            inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
                GetInAddress((struct sockaddr *) &their_addr), s, sizeof s);
            printf("> Server: got connection from %s\n", s);

            requestStack[stackTop++] = new_fd;
            printf("> Server: stack top is now %i with value %i.\n", stackTop, requestStack[stackTop-1]);
        }

        // MAGICAL TEST: continue;

        // Linear search for a free worker thread...
        unsigned int i;
        int rc;
        for (i = 0; i < g_NumWorkers && stackTop > 0; i++) {
            rc = pthread_mutex_trylock(&(g_Workers[i].m_Mutex));
            if (rc == EBUSY)  // If it was already locked, skip worker thread.
                continue;
            else if (!rc) { // If we managed to lock the thread's mutex...
                if (g_Workers[i].m_ClientFD == -1) { // Check if it is currently out of work.
                    g_Workers[i].m_ClientFD = requestStack[--stackTop];
                    printf("> Server: master thread assigned fd %i to thread %u\n", requestStack[stackTop], i);
                }
                rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&(g_Workers[i].m_Mutex));
                if (rc) {
                    printf("> Server: main thread mutex unlock failed on thread %i with error %i!\n", i, rc);
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            else
                printf("> Server: main thread try-lock failed on thread %i with error %i!\n", i, rc);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My apologies for the verbosity of the code and for possibly having missed any basic information from the man pages.

As requested, here is the slave thread function:

```
static void *WorkRoutine(void *args) {
    ThreadData * const threadData = (ThreadData*) args;
    pthread_mutex_t * const tMutex = &(threadData->m_Mutex);
    const unsigned int tIndex = threadData->m_Index;
    int clientFD = threadData->m_ClientFD;

    // Each thread initializes its own mutex.
    int rc = pthread_mutex_init(tMutex, NULL);
    if (!rc)
        printf("> Slave %u: mutex %p initialization was sucessful!\n", tIndex, tMutex);
    if (rc && rc != PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD) {
        printf("> Slave %u: failed mutex initialization!\n", tIndex);
        perror("pthread_mutex_init");
        exit(-1); //TODO: implement graceful error exit.
    }

    // Synchronization point: all threads including the master thread wait for all slave mutexes to be initialized.
    rc = pthread_barrier_wait(&g_StartBarrier);
    if (rc && rc != PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD) {
        printf("> Slave %u: failed initial barrier synchronization!\n", tIndex);
        perror("pthread_barrier_wait");
        exit(-1); //TODO: implement graceful error exit.
    }

    while (1) { //TODO replace 1 with state var that is turned off when the master thread receives a request to shutdown server.
        rc = pthread_mutex_lock(tMutex);
        if (rc) {
            printf("> Slave %u: mutex lock returned an error: %i!\n", tIndex, rc);
            perror("pthread_mutex_lock()");
            continue;
        }
        clientFD = threadData->m_ClientFD;
        if (!threadData->m_Task && clientFD == -1) {
            rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(tMutex);
            int yieldStatus = sched_yield();
            if (yieldStatus) {
                printf("> Slave %u: error while attempting to yield!\n", tIndex);
                perror("sched_yield()\n");
            }
            continue;
            //printf("> Slave %u: yielding.\n", tIndex);
        }
        else if (!threadData->m_Task && clientFD != -1) {
            // Read client request.
            threadData->m_Task = (char*) calloc(FILE_BUFFER, sizeof(char)); //TODO: stop allocating buffer on every task.
            printf("> Slave %u going to read from %i into %p\n", tIndex, clientFD, threadData->m_Task);

            MessageHeader h;
            GetHeader(&h, clientFD);
            if (h.m_ID != BeginSession) {
                //protocol implementation error
                exit(-1);
            }
            printf("> Slave %u: expecting client command of length %i\n", tIndex, h.m_ContentSize);
            int n = GetContent((void*) threadData->m_Task, h.m_ContentSize * sizeof(char), clientFD);
            printf("> Slave %u: client of file descriptor %i sent [%s] at a total of %i bytes\n", tIndex, clientFD, threadData->m_Task, n);
            short int remoteOperation;

            int baseArgvSize = 10;
            char **argv = (char**) calloc(baseArgvSize, sizeof(char*)); //TODO: stop allocating table on every task.
            int argc = CmdToTable(threadData->m_Task, &argv, &baseArgvSize);

            int localLen = strlen("local");
            int remoteLen = strlen("remote");

            if(!strncmp(threadData->m_Task, "remote", remoteLen)) {
                remoteOperation = 1;
                g_Workers[tIndex].m_Networking = 1;

            }
            else if(!strncmp(threadData->m_Task, "local", localLen)) {
                remoteOperation = 0;
                g_Workers[tIndex].m_Networking = 0;
                g_Workers[tIndex].m_OutputDir = (char*) calloc(FILE_BUFFER, sizeof(char));

                MessageHeader hPath;
                GetHeader(&hPath, clientFD);
                if (hPath.m_ID != SendMessage) {
                    //protocol implementation error
                    exit(-1);
                }

                int cnt = GetContent((void*) g_Workers[tIndex].m_OutputDir, hPath.m_ContentSize * sizeof(char), clientFD);
                g_Workers[tIndex].m_OutputDir[hPath.m_ContentSize * sizeof(char)] = '/';
                printf("> Slave %u: received message with %i bytes.\n", tIndex, cnt);
                printf("> Slave %u: client output going to %s\n", tIndex, g_Workers[tIndex].m_OutputDir);
            }
            else {
                printf("> Slave %u: received bogus client command: %s\n", tIndex, threadData->m_Task);
                return NULL;
            }
            printf("> Slave %u: remote mode - %i.\n", tIndex, g_Workers[tIndex].m_Networking);
            // Debug print the table built from the client command.
            printf("> Slave %u: table has %i entries.\n", tIndex, argc);
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
                printf("> Slave %u: argument %i is %s.\n", tIndex, i, argv[i]);
            }
            // Prepare the input files the client will send.
            char**filenames = (char**) calloc(argc, sizeof(char*));
            FILE**files = (FILE**) calloc(argc, sizeof(FILE*));
            unsigned int reqIDIndex = 0;
            unsigned int reqIDLen = strlen(argv[reqIDIndex]);

            if(!remoteOperation)
                continue;

            // Check which files need to be sent from the client.
            for (i = reqIDIndex + 1; i < argc; i++) {
                unsigned int argSize = strlen(argv[i]);
                if (strstr(argv[i], FILETYPE_SEPARATOR) != NULL
                        && strstr(argv[i], INDEX_FILETYPE) == NULL) {
                    // If the current argument has a file type and isn't an index type.
                    filenames[i] = calloc(reqIDLen + argSize + 2, sizeof(char)); // +2 to account for terminator char and hyphen between reqID and filename

                    printf("> Slave %u: arg %s check with req %s\n", tIndex, argv[i], argv[reqIDIndex]);
                    int noReqYet = strncmp(argv[i], argv[reqIDIndex], reqIDLen);
                    if (noReqYet) {
                        printf("> Slave %u: no prepended request yet!\n", tIndex);
                        strncpy(filenames[i], argv[reqIDIndex], reqIDLen);
                        filenames[i][reqIDLen] = '-';
                    }
                    // If the argument is a path to a file, get the filename and discard the path (that was local to the client).
                    char*nameStart = strrchr(argv[i], '/'); //TODO: make a define for 92: backslash ascii char number
                    printf("> Slave %u: going to remove backslash from %s\n", tIndex, argv[i]);

                    if (nameStart != NULL )
                        nameStart++;
                    else
                        nameStart = argv[i];

                    printf("> Slave %u: got %s after removing backslash\n", tIndex, nameStart);
                    printf("noReqYet: %i\n", noReqYet);
                    if (!noReqYet)
                        strncpy(filenames[i], nameStart, strlen(nameStart));
                    else
                        strncpy(filenames[i] + reqIDLen + 1, nameStart,
                                strlen(nameStart)); //+1 to account for the hyphen.
                    // When freeing the argv table, only need to free(argv). There is no need to free argv[i] elements.
                    argv[i] = filenames[i];
                }
                else if (strstr(argv[i], FILETYPE_SEPARATOR) != NULL && strstr(argv[i], INDEX_FILETYPE) != NULL ) {
                    // If the current argument is the index type.
                    char*nameStart = strrchr(argv[i], '/');
                    if (nameStart != NULL ) {
                        nameStart++;
                        argv[i] = nameStart;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Debug print the needed files.
            printf("> Slave %u: awaiting files:", tIndex);
            for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
                if (filenames[i] != NULL ) {
                    printf(" %s", filenames[i]);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");

            // Await each input file from the client.
            for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
                if (filenames[i] != NULL ) {
                    files[i] = GetFile(clientFD, filenames[i]); // Note: GetFile invokes fclose!
                    if (files[i])
                        printf("> Slave %u: locally stored file %s\n", tIndex, filenames[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        printf("> Slave %u: going to invoke SatisfyRequest with arguments: ", tIndex);
        for (i = reqIDIndex; i < argc; i++) {
            if (argv[i] != NULL )
                printf("%s ", argv[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        // Process the request against the index.
        int res = SatisfyRequest(argc, argv, tIndex, clientFD);

        char* dummy;
        if (!res)
            dummy = "Your request succeeded.";
        else
            dummy = "Sorry, there was an error.";

        // Terminate session with the client.
        SendMsg(EndSession, (void*)dummy, strlen(dummy), clientFD);
        printf("> Slave %u: task result delivered to client of file descriptor %i.\n", tIndex, clientFD);
        close(clientFD);
        free(threadData->m_Task);
        free(argv);
        if(!remoteOperation) {
            free(g_Workers[tIndex].m_OutputDir);
        }
        // Free received file names and file pointer array.
        for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
            if (filenames[i])
                free(filenames[i]);
        }
        free(filenames);
        free(files);

        // Reset thread-local data.
        threadData->m_Task = NULL;
        threadData->m_ClientFD = -1;
        clientFD = -1;

        printf("> Slave %u: task finished.\n", tIndex);
        rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(tMutex);
        if(!rc)
            continue;
    }
    if (rc) {
        printf("> Slave %u: mutex unlock returned an error: %i!\n", tIndex, rc);
        perror("pthread_mutex_unlock()");
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

This is the client-side part of the code:

```
char*cmdBuffer = (char*)calloc(FILE_BUFFER, sizeof(char));
char*cmdRealPath = (char*)calloc(FILE_BUFFER, sizeof(char));
int auxNameTableSz = 25;
char**auxNameTable = (char**)calloc(auxNameTableSz, sizeof(char*));

char* ip = argv[2];
char* port = argv[3];
char* networkMode = argv[4];
//  char* reqID = argv[5];
const int cmdStartIndex = 6;
short int remoteOperation;

if(!strcmp(networkMode, "remote")) {
    remoteOperation = 1;
    auxNameTableSz = 0;
}
else if(!strcmp(networkMode, "local")) {
    // If the client is on the server's machine, need to convert argument files to absolute paths.
    remoteOperation = 0;
    int i = cmdStartIndex;
    int j = 0;
    while(i < argc) {
        if(strrchr(argv[i], '/') || strrchr(argv[i], '.')) {
            argv[i] = realpath(argv[i], NULL);
            auxNameTable[j++] = argv[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    auxNameTableSz = j;
}
else {
    printf("> Client: argument four must be either \"global\" or \"local\"!");
    free(cmdBuffer);
    free(cmdRealPath);
    FreePathsTable(&auxNameTable, auxNameTableSz);
    DeallocateGlobals();
    return 0;
}

// Concatenate client arguments into a single string.
MakeCommand(argc, argv, cmdBuffer);
printf("> Client: [Command]: %s\n", cmdBuffer);

// Establish a (TCP) connection with the server.
if(PrepareConnection(ip, port)) {
    // Failed to prepare connection.
    free(cmdBuffer);
    free(cmdRealPath);
    FreePathsTable(&auxNameTable, auxNameTableSz);
  DeallocateGlobals();
    return 0;
}
if(ConnectToServer()) {
    // Failed to establish a stream socket connection.
    free(cmdBuffer);
    free(cmdRealPath);
    FreePathsTable(&auxNameTable, auxNameTableSz);
    DeallocateGlobals();
    return 0;
}

// Send the client command to the server.
printf("> Client: sending command of %i bytes to server: [%s].\n", (int)strlen(cmdBuffer), cmdBuffer);
int count=0;
if((count=WriteToServer(BeginSession, cmdBuffer)) == -1) {
    // Command send failed.
    free(cmdBuffer);
    free(cmdRealPath);
    FreePathsTable(&auxNameTable, auxNameTableSz);
    DeallocateGlobals();
    return 0;
}
printf("> Client sent command to the server at %i bytes.\n", count);
if(remoteOperation) {
        // Send the correct input files to the server.
        SendInputFiles(argc, argv, cmdStartIndex);
}
else {
    // Send the real path of the client's working directory to the server.
    char *localDir = realpath(".", NULL);
    count=WriteToServer(SendMessage, localDir);
printf("> Client sent the real path to the server at %i bytes.\n", count);
    free(localDir);
}

// Await reply from the server.
char *buffer = (char*) calloc(FILE_BUFFER, sizeof(char));
count = ReceiveFromServer(buffer);

char *backPtr = buffer;

if(remoteOperation) {
    printf("> Client: got output list [%s] totalling %i bytes.\n", buffer, count);
    // Receive the files produced by the server if the client and server are not on the same machine.
    ReceiveOutputFiles(buffer);

    // Await session termination.
        buffer = backPtr;
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(char)*FILE_BUFFER);
        count = ReceiveFromServer(buffer);

}
else {

}

printf("> Client: server response: [%s]-[%s]\n", buffer, cmdBuffer);
```

Comment: what is the value of g_NumWorkers?

Comment: On the scenario that fails, g_NumWorkers = 2, representing two slaves.

Comment: Sorry for the extra comment: the idea is that while a slave satisfies a request, its mutex remains locked, so it will be skipped on the trylock of the master thread. So if all slaves are busy, incoming requests would be stored in the stack, and eventually assigned to a slave when it became free.

Comment: ok, but something maybe wrong with `rc==EBUSY`, did you mean `errno==EBUSY`? the pthread_mutex_trylock returns non-zero when failed.

Comment: and would you mind post the work thread's code?

Comment: I added the code of the slave threads. I apologise for its length... Regarding pthread_mutex_trylock: the man pages state (pthread_mutex_trylock(3p)) that if a problem happens, an error number shall be returned to indicate the error. EBUSY is one of the possible return errors, meaning that the mutex is currently locked.

Comment: Why don't you use a queue with a mutex and a condition variable, aka. thread safe queue, for the communication between the master thread and the workers, that should greatly simplify the design...

Comment: still finding no problems... but what if 2 slavers with 7/8/9 concurrent threads?

Comment: @SegFault : do you mean like using only a mutex to safeguard the client socket queue and have the slaves call pthread_cond_wait() on a variable such as the number of elements in the queue? I would then be reducing the number of mutexes to one, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Marcus : I'm not sure I understand: do you mean using a two-thread pool and with 7/8/9 concurrent client requests? If that's what you mean, then that's exactly the situation resulting in problems. If I include the "MAGICAL" continue, the master thread reports all requests. Otherwise, some accept printfs just seem to vanish!

Comment: Yes, you're right. So the situation is that when there's more concurrent requests than slavers, the server just stop printing requests after some time?

Comment: That is the apparent behaviour indeed. I find it quite odd because there can be (in theory) no deadlocks in the master thread task delivery (pthread_mutex_trylock() plus an unlock shortly after), so I was at least expecting that the master thread would still announce the other connections though.  I'm also skeptical that one of the slaves is somehow influencing the internal state of the C libraries or the master thread's stack...

Comment: @Marcus: Do you think this is some internal limit in the system leading to the **listen()** call ignoring PENDING_CONNS?

Comment: ...eh.. I wonder if there's a deadlock.. , though `pthread_mutex_trylock` says itself is `non-blocking`, try to add some debug printing after `rc = pthread_mutex_trylock(&(g_Workers[i].m_Mutex));`?

Comment: After you `accept` a connection, the connection is removed from the queue, so I don't think it is the factor..

Comment: @Marcus: will do so soon, get back to you when I do. However, I remember previously running a print at the end of the linear free slave search, and it never stopped printing!

Comment: Eh, what about your test client code?

Comment: In the client code, as soon as the TCP connection is established, it successfully sends a command to the server. The networking functions used by the client are not triggering any errors, and are returning the byte count of the sent message. The client is then stuck in a blocking receive (from the client point-of-view it is fine). But now that you mention it, if the connection seems to be fine in the client, does it mean that the server is correctly receiving the request (and socket from accept), but multi-threaded activity is hiding the success print and leaving the task unattended?

Comment: @Marcus: I added the client-side code. I'm using some abstractions over the networking part of the code, I can provide those as well if you wish. If I wait terribly long after the server delivers the results of **5 out of 6** requests and close the server manually, the waiting client executes the last message **printf("> Client: server response: [%s]-[%s]\n", buffer, cmdBuffer);**...

Comment: when the server stop printing requests, use an other client(like `telnet`) to connect the server, and what will be happened?

Comment: @mcoimbra Yes, that's the way to go.

Comment: I figured it out. The use of the local **clientFD** variable in the **WorkRoutine function** was interfering with the logic of the thread synchronisation... I was using that variable for legibility (half-assed I know). I replaced it with direct use of the thread structure FD variable and it is now working.

Comment: Can you please post your solution as an answer below? Thanks.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, I realize that quite some time has passed since I posted, my apologies. The problem was literally solved as described in my last comment. Shall I answer my own question with the information of that comment and some context on the original problem? Is that the best approach?

Comment: Yes, please. Any details you can add that might help someone else who has the same or similar problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Took a while but here it is. Were the negative votes due to the delay or just without a reason? Anyway @BilltheLizard, it is finally posted.

Comment: Why are you using non-blocking mode for the listening socket when all you do when there is no incoming connection is spin? This is very poor practice. Either use `select()` to tell you when to call `accept(),` or use blocking mode.

Comment: @EJP it is not the best design in my opinion. But it isn't simply spinning. It also checks if there are unattended connections and, if so, dispatches them to a worker thread. Something like what SegFault suggested would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this answer was way overdue, but here it is.

The use of the local `clientFD` variable in the `WorkRoutine` function was interfering with the logic of the thread synchronization... I was using that variable temporarily for legibility and I overlooked the fact that it could interfere with the correct operation of the threads. I replaced it with direct use of the thread structure FD variable and it is now working (`threadData->m_ClientFD`).

I present the final code below:

```
static void *WorkRoutine(void *args) {
// Easier access of thread-local data.
ThreadData * const threadData = (ThreadData*) args;
pthread_mutex_t * const tMutex = &(threadData->m_Mutex);
const unsigned int tIndex = threadData->m_Index;

threadData->m_StatIndex = 0;
threadData->m_StatCount = BASE_TASK_COUNT;
threadData->m_OutputDir = NULL;
threadData->errorFileName = (char*) calloc(FILE_BUFFER, sizeof(char));

char *logName = (char*) calloc(FILE_BUFFER, sizeof(char));
const char *baseName = "./log-t";
size_t baseNameSize = strlen(baseName);
memcpy(logName, baseName, baseNameSize);
sprintf(logName + baseNameSize, "%u", threadData->m_Index);
threadData->m_Log = stdout;
#if defined LOGGING
threadData->m_Log = fopen(logName, "w");
#endif


fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: log file %s at pointer %p.\n", tIndex, logName, threadData->m_Log);

// Each thread initializes its own mutex.
int rc = pthread_mutex_init(tMutex, NULL);
if (!rc)
    fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: mutex %p initialization was successful!\n", tIndex, tMutex);
if (rc != 0 && rc != PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD) {
    fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: failed mutex initialization!\n", tIndex);
    perror("pthread_mutex_init");
    exit(-1);
}

// Each thread will also need to find out its own clock id.
int clkStatus = pthread_getcpuclockid(threadData->m_Thread, &(threadData->m_CID));
if (clkStatus != 0)
    handle_error_en(clkStatus, "pthread_getcpuclockid");


// Synchronization point: all threads including the master thread wait for all slave mutexes to be initialized.
rc = pthread_barrier_wait(&g_StartBarrier);
if (rc != 0 && rc != PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD) {
    fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: failed initial barrier synchronization!\n", tIndex);
    perror("pthread_barrier_wait");
    exit(-1); 
}

while (1) { 
    threadData->m_OutputDir = NULL;

    // Check if server was ordered to shutdown.
    rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&g_ShutdownLock);
    if(!rc) {
        if(g_ShutdownOrdered) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_ShutdownLock);
            break;
        }
        else {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_ShutdownLock);
        }
    }
    else {
        fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: failed on mutex lock of shutdown lock: %i\n", tIndex, rc);
        perror("slave: pthread_mutex_lock");
    }


    rc = pthread_mutex_lock(tMutex);
    if (!rc) {
        if (!threadData->m_Task && threadData->m_ClientFD == -1) {
            rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(tMutex);
            int yieldStatus = sched_yield();
            if (yieldStatus) {
                fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: error while attempting to yield!\n", tIndex);
                perror("sched_yield()\n");
            }
            continue;
            //printf("> Slave %u: yielding.\n", tIndex);
        }
        else if (!threadData->m_Task && threadData->m_ClientFD != -1) {
            // Read client request.
            threadData->m_Task = (char*) calloc(FILE_BUFFER, sizeof(char)); 
            memset(threadData->m_Task, 0, FILE_BUFFER * sizeof(char));
            fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: going to read from %i into %p\n", tIndex, threadData->m_ClientFD, threadData->m_Task);

            MessageHeader h;
            GetHeader(&h, threadData->m_ClientFD);


            // In case we received an order to kill the server.
            if(h.m_ID == CloseServer) {
                fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: got order to close server!\n", tIndex);
                rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&g_ShutdownLock);
                if(!rc) {
                    g_ShutdownOrdered = 1;
                    free(threadData->m_Task);
                    pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_ShutdownLock);
                    // Reset thread-local data.
                    threadData->m_Task = NULL;
                    close(threadData->m_ClientFD);
                    threadData->m_ClientFD = -1;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: failed locking of shutdown lock: %i", tIndex, rc);
                    perror("pthread_mutex_lock");
                }
            }

            if (h.m_ID != BeginSession) {
                //protocol implementation error
                exit(-1);
            }


            clock_gettime(threadData->m_CID, &(threadData->m_PrevTime));
            fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: expecting client command of length %i\n", tIndex, h.m_ContentSize);
            int n = GetContent((void*) threadData->m_Task, h.m_ContentSize * sizeof(char), threadData->m_ClientFD);
            fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: client of file descriptor %i sent [%s] at a total of %i bytes\n", tIndex, threadData->m_ClientFD, threadData->m_Task, n);

            int baseArgvSize = 10;
            char **argv = (char**) calloc(baseArgvSize, sizeof(char*)); 
            int argc = CmdToTable(threadData->m_Task, &argv, &baseArgvSize, threadData->m_Log);

            int localLen = strlen("local");
            int remoteLen = strlen("remote");

            if(!strncmp(threadData->m_Task, "remote", remoteLen)) {
                g_Workers[tIndex].m_Networking = 1;
            }
            else if(!strncmp(threadData->m_Task, "local", localLen)) {
                g_Workers[tIndex].m_Networking = 0;
                g_Workers[tIndex].m_OutputDir = (char*) calloc(FILE_BUFFER, sizeof(char));

                MessageHeader hPath;
                GetHeader(&hPath, threadData->m_ClientFD);
                if (hPath.m_ID != SendMessage) {
                    //protocol implementation error
                    exit(-1);
                }


                int cnt = GetContent((void*) threadData->m_OutputDir, hPath.m_ContentSize * sizeof(char), threadData->m_ClientFD);
                printf("> Slave %u: I RECEIVED %s AS OUTPUT DIRECTORY!\n\n\n\n\n", tIndex, threadData->m_OutputDir);
                threadData->m_OutputDir[hPath.m_ContentSize * sizeof(char)] = '/';



                fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: received output directory message with %i bytes.\n", tIndex, cnt);
                fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: client output going to %s\n", tIndex, threadData->m_OutputDir);
            }
            else {
                fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: received bogus client command: %s\n", tIndex, threadData->m_Task);
                return NULL;
            }
            fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: remote mode - %i.\n", tIndex, g_Workers[tIndex].m_Networking);
            // Debug print the table built from the client command.
            fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: table has %i entries.\n", tIndex, argc);
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
                fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: argument %i is %s.\n", tIndex, i, argv[i]);
            }
            // Prepare the input files the client will send.
            char**filenames = (char**) calloc(argc, sizeof(char*));
            FILE**files = (FILE**) calloc(argc, sizeof(FILE*));
            unsigned int reqIDIndex = 0;
            unsigned int reqIDLen = strlen(argv[reqIDIndex]);
            threadData->m_REQ = argv[reqIDIndex];
            if(threadData->m_Networking) {
                // Check which files need to be sent from the client.
                for (i = reqIDIndex + 1; i < argc; i++) {
                    unsigned int argSize = strlen(argv[i]);
                    if (strstr(argv[i], FILETYPE_SEPARATOR) != NULL
                            && strstr(argv[i], INDEX_FILETYPE) == NULL) {
                        // If the current argument has a file type and isn't an index type.
                        filenames[i] = calloc(reqIDLen + argSize + 2, sizeof(char)); // +2 to account for terminator char and hyphen between reqID and filename

                        fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: arg %s check with req %s\n", tIndex, argv[i], argv[reqIDIndex]);
                        int noReqYet = strncmp(argv[i], argv[reqIDIndex], reqIDLen);
                        if (noReqYet) {
                            fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: no prepended request yet!\n", tIndex);
                            strncpy(filenames[i], argv[reqIDIndex], reqIDLen);
                            filenames[i][reqIDLen] = '-';
                        }
                        // If the argument is a path to a file, get the filename and discard the path (that was local to the client).
                        char*nameStart = strrchr(argv[i], '/'); 
                        fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: going to remove backslash from %s\n", tIndex, argv[i]);

                        if (nameStart != NULL )
                            nameStart++;
                        else
                            nameStart = argv[i];

                        fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: got %s after removing backslash\n", tIndex, nameStart);
                        fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "noReqYet: %i\n", noReqYet);
                        if (!noReqYet)
                            strncpy(filenames[i], nameStart, strlen(nameStart));
                        else
                            strncpy(filenames[i] + reqIDLen + 1, nameStart,
                                    strlen(nameStart)); //+1 to account for the hyphen.
                        // When freeing the argv table, only need to free(argv). There is no need to free argv[i] elements.
                        argv[i] = filenames[i];
                    } else if (strstr(argv[i], FILETYPE_SEPARATOR) != NULL
                            && strstr(argv[i], INDEX_FILETYPE) != NULL ) {
                        // If the current argument is the index type.
                        char*nameStart = strrchr(argv[i], '/');
                        if (nameStart != NULL ) {
                            nameStart++;
                            argv[i] = nameStart;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Debug print the needed files.
                fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: awaiting files:", tIndex);
                for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
                    if (filenames[i] != NULL ) {
                        fprintf(threadData->m_Log, " %s", filenames[i]);
                    }
                }
                fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "\n");

                // Await each input file from the client.
                for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
                    if (filenames[i] != NULL ) {
                        files[i] = GetFile(threadData->m_ClientFD, filenames[i]); // Note: GetFile invokes fclose!
                        if (files[i])
                            fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: locally stored file %s\n", tIndex, filenames[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: going to invoke SatisfyRequest with arguments: ", tIndex);
            for (i = reqIDIndex; i < argc; i++) {
                if (argv[i] != NULL )
                    fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "%s ", argv[i]);
            }
            fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "\n");

            // Process the request against the index.
            int res = SatisfyRequest(argc, argv, tIndex, threadData->m_ClientFD);
            char success = 0;
            if(!res)
                success = 1;

            // Terminate session with the client.
            SendMsg(EndSession, (void*)&success, sizeof(success), threadData->m_ClientFD);
            fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: task result delivered to client of file descriptor %i.\n", tIndex, threadData->m_ClientFD);
            close(threadData->m_ClientFD);

            free(argv);
            threadData->m_REQ = NULL;
            if(!threadData->m_Networking) {
                free(threadData->m_OutputDir);
                threadData->m_OutputDir = NULL;
            }

            // Free received file names and file pointer array.
            for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
                if (filenames[i]) {
                    free(filenames[i]);
                    filenames[i] = NULL;
                }
            }
            free(filenames);
            free(files);
            filenames = NULL;
            files = NULL;
            // Print out the time it took for the task.
            struct timespec tempTime;
            clock_gettime(threadData->m_CID, &tempTime);

            struct timespec timeDelta;
            timeDelta.tv_nsec = tempTime.tv_nsec - threadData->m_PrevTime.tv_nsec;
            timeDelta.tv_sec = tempTime.tv_sec - threadData->m_PrevTime.tv_sec;

            if(timeDelta.tv_nsec < 0)
                timeDelta.tv_nsec *= -1;
            if(timeDelta.tv_sec < 0)
                timeDelta.tv_sec *= -1;

            RegisterStat(tIndex, threadData->m_StatIndex++, timeDelta, threadData->m_Task);

            fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "Slave %u: %4ld.%03ld\n", tIndex, timeDelta.tv_sec,timeDelta.tv_nsec / 1000000);
            memcpy(&(threadData->m_PrevTime), &tempTime, sizeof(struct timespec));

            // Reset thread-local data.
            memset(threadData->m_Task, 0, FILE_BUFFER * sizeof(char));
            free(threadData->m_Task);
            threadData->m_Task = NULL;
            threadData->m_ClientFD = -1;
            fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: task finished.\n", tIndex);
            rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(tMutex);
        }
        if (rc) {
            fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: mutex unlock returned an error: %i!\n", tIndex, rc);
            perror("pthread_mutex_unlock()");
        }
    } else {
        fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: mutex lock returned an error: %i!\n", tIndex, rc);
        perror("pthread_mutex_lock()");
    }
}
free(threadData->errorFileName);
threadData->errorFileName = NULL;
free(logName);
logName = NULL;
fprintf(threadData->m_Log, "> Slave %u: exiting...\n", tIndex);

#if defined LOGGING
    fclose(threadData->m_Log);
#endif
threadData->m_Log = NULL;

return 0;
}
```